# Is SameSite=Strict cookie protection broken in Chrome & Firefox?

Tags: session-cookies, csrf, samesite

It seems that the CSRF protection attribute "SameSite=Strict" does not offer the required protection in all cases.

Scenario 1 (works):

- User logs in on `https://example.com`. Session cookie is set, protected with "SameSite=Strict".
- User visits `https://attack-1abc2def.com`. Cross-origin form POST to `https://example.com/foo` does not send the session cookie along, fine, protection works.

Scenario 2 (broken):

- Log in on `https://example.com` as above. A session cookie is set:
  `Set-cookie: PHPSESSID=1234; path=/; domain=.example.com; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict`
- User visits `https://attack-1abc2def.com`. This website makes a cross-origin form POST to `https://example.com/login`.
  The session cookie is not sent along, since protected with `SameSite=Strict`.
  BUT: The `/login` route sets a new session cookie
  `Set-cookie: PHPSESSID=9876; path=/; domain=.example.com; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict`
  . (Some frameworks, like Symfony, set a new session cookie for every login request, regardless if successful or not.)
  This cookie is STORED and therefore REPLACES the valid session cookie - in spite of the `SameSite` flag.
  -> Even though the previous session is still valid, the browser no longer uses it, so the user is effectively logged out.

I tested this in Chrome/78.0.3904.108 and in Firefox/70.0.
The CSRF protection works fine for Scenario 1 since I added the "SameSite=Strict" flag, but has the described problem in Scenario 2.

Did the "SameSite" cookie specification (or the browser developers) maybe miss the Scenario 2?
I was hoping that special CSRF protection measures are no longer necessary with the "SameSite" flag.

IMHO, the "SameSite" flag should not only protect from sending existing cookies, but also from storing new ones.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing some nuance in your question, but it sounds as if you're asking if a server sends this on one request: `Set-cookie: foo=bar; SameSite=Strict` and then sends `Set-cookie: foo=updated` on a subsequent request, will it overwrite the original? My understanding is that this is intended. The server is responsible for not sending cookies with the same name with less secure options.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @rowan_m. In my case, all cookies are set with `SameSite=strict`. I've updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: Since the observed bahavior seems to be against the spec (https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-cookie-same-site-00 / section 4.2), I asked the spec authors for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior. All top-level requests can set SameSite cookies. This is reflected in the latest version of the spec: https://github.com/httpwg/http-extensions/pull/800

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [SameSite cookies explained](https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/):

> the cookie will only be sent if the site for the cookie matches the site currently shown in the browser's URL bar.

This means that `SameSite=Strict` or `SameSite=Lax` wil act as a protecting mechanism ***only for the first step*** of the cross site communication, i.e. when the user first click the link from one site to another. Following navigations will use cookies since URL origin will be the same.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to the question.

Comment: I was assuming that probably the app on example.com was redirecting and the redirected route was responsible for creating the new cookie. After looking back, I realize that wasn't the case. Sorry for confusion.